# My PHP website got hacked and the hacker uploaded and moved around some files. How could this have happened?

Tags: php, security

I Googled this and a common risk seemed to be include() or require() statements that accept URL parameters. I don't have anything like that on the site; any includes have the paths hardcoded.

As far as I know, there is only one area on the front end that actually accepts file uploads, and it does not store files in the directory that my host said the rogue files were initially uploaded to.

Would the hacker have to have had FTP access to do what they did? What else could I check for? Thank you.

Comment: Try asking for help on what would be the first few steps to take in order to investigate this by asking at http://serverfault.com/ or http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

You really should post some of your suspected vulnerable code here, but here's a tip:

server logs will tell you a lot. It is possible this person ran a script that just constantly pings your site with a basic remote ftp request over and over until they get in thanks to a weak password or blind luck.

Additionally, if you don't purify input you can do a lot of damage just by clever use of $_POST, $_GET, or $_REQUEST vars. clean all input before running anything with the vars.

Any more suggestions will definitely need some kind of code to audit.

my 2 cents

Answer (score 2):

Check the webserver logs for any hits on the rogue files, then gather all log entries for that IP. You might be able to see a POST where the file was uploaded.

If your host makes them available, check the ftp logs - this should be a little easier as the logs will be smaller. Look for any unexpected IP addresses.

By far the most common holes I see are weak passwords (either ftp or web admin passwords) or badly configured hosting (which is a common problem with cheap hosts).